# Creatin EAR file from existing Maven Project via Gradle

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle, migration, ear

I have an existing maven project, and through Eclipse, I can perfectly run the root part as "Maven Build" and get my EAR files and all. Now, I want to do this using gradle. I tried "Buildship Gradle Integration" for eclipse, I tried to do it manually but I wasn't able to obtain the same result as I did with Maven. How do I do do same thing using Gradle?

Comment: You need to write a Gradle build script to get that working...

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that exactly, what should it contain?

Comment: Sorry to broad for SO better start reading the docs about Gradle....